# How to automatic increase mysql table row values

Tags: mysql

I want to ask, how to automatically increase MySQL table row values

I have this table:

```
INSERT INTO `ps_product_attribute` (`id_product_attribute`, `id_product`, `reference`, `supplier_reference`, `location`, `ean13`, `upc`, `wholesale_price`, `price`, `ecotax`, `quantity`, `weight`, `unit_price_impact`, `default_on`, `minimal_quantity`, `available_date`) VALUES
(140, 2, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 7.317073, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 1, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(141, 2, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 14.634146, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(142, 2, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 24.390244, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(143, 3, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 7.317073, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 1, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(144, 3, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 14.634146, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(145, 3, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 24.390244, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00');
```

This describes two products with three attributes with price. How to make this for 213 other products like here:

```
INSERT INTO `ps_product_attribute` (`id_product_attribute`, `id_product`, `reference`, `supplier_reference`, `location`, `ean13`, `upc`, `wholesale_price`, `price`, `ecotax`, `quantity`, `weight`, `unit_price_impact`, `default_on`, `minimal_quantity`, `available_date`) VALUES
(140, 2, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 7.317073, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 1, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(141, 2, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 14.634146, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(142, 2, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 24.390244, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(143, 3, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 7.317073, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 1, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(144, 3, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 14.634146, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(145, 3, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 24.390244, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00');
(146, 4, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 7.317073, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 1, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(147, 4, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 14.634146, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(148, 4, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 24.390244, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(149, 5, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 7.317073, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 1, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(150, 5, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 14.634146, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(151, 5, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 24.390244, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00');
.
.
.
```

The last id_product should be 216.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking...

Comment: Hi. Yes because i dont know sql ;/ I want to increase id_product (up to 216) and id_product_attribute with price (adequate). Like in second example

Comment: I don't know what do you want? But if you want column id_product_attribute auto increment, please set it in mysql.

Comment: But how to make it automatic via mysql query?

Comment: Maybe this way. I have table like in first example. Only 2 products (ID 2 and 3)
I want to fill this table manualy with other 214 id's via sql query... Fist column with step of one 140, 141, 142... and second column with step by 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 and the price columnt with step like this 7.317073, 14.634146, 24.390244, 7.317073, 14.634146, 24.390244, 7.317073, 14.634146, 24.390244,

Comment: Thanks everybody for effort and time! I found easy way to solve it by export database to csv, edit in excel, save to csv and import to database. works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for the AUTO_INCREMENT specification for your id column.
You should look at this link in order to understand properly how to manage your table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Set field id_product_attribute auto increment

```
ALTER TABLE ps_product_attribute MODIFY COLUMN id_product_attribute  INT auto_increment
```

Step 2: remove column id_product_attribute from insert script and create procudure (replace number 1000 with number of product that you want). Example:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS abc $$
CREATE PROCEDURE abc()
BEGIN
   DECLARE a INT Default 1 ;
      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET a=a+1;
         INSERT INTO `ps_product_attribute` (`id_product`, `reference`, `supplier_reference`, `location`, `ean13`, `upc`, `wholesale_price`, `price`, `ecotax`, `quantity`, `weight`, `unit_price_impact`, `default_on`, `minimal_quantity`, `available_date`) VALUES
(a, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 7.317073, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 1, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(a, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 14.634146, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00'),
(a, '', '', '', '', '', 0.000000, 24.390244, 0.000000, 100, 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 1, '0000-00-00');
         IF a=1000 THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
   END LOOP simple_loop;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

STEP 3: run procedure

Comment: I have table like in first example. Only 2 products (ID 2 and 3) I want to fill this table manualy with other 214 id's via sql query... Fist column with step of one 140, 141, 142... and second column with step by 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 and the price columnt with step like this 7.317073, 14.634146, 24.390244, 7.317073, 14.634146, 24.390244, 7.317073, 14.634146, 24.390244

Comment: thanks but i cant remove id_product_attribute column :( 
Its a part of the system.

Comment: that field will auto increment, you will not remove from your system.

Comment: Ah, ok :)
I have this issue
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@a INT Default 1 ; simple_loop: LOOP SET @a=@a+1; INS' at line 4

Comment: Thanks everybody for effort and time! I found easy way to solve it by export database to csv, edit in excel, save to csv and import to database. works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

Create a procedure to generate `id_product` values from a pre specified number to a desired max number say `216` and run insert using those values in a loop.

Following example is written, assuming that `id_product_attribute` in an `auto_increment` column.

**Example**

```
delimiter //
drop procedure add_dummy_records //
create procedure add_dummy_records( inout id_product_start int, in max_id int )
begin
  declare start_id int;
  -- declare query text;

   set start_id = id_product_start;
  set @query := 'INSERT INTO `ps_product_attribute` 
                 (`id_product`, `reference`, `supplier_reference`, 
                  `location`, `ean13`, `upc`, 
                  `wholesale_price`, `price`, `ecotax`, 
                  `quantity`, `weight`, `unit_price_impact`, 
                  `default_on`, `minimal_quantity`, `available_date`
                 ) VALUES\n';

  adding_rows: loop
    if ( start_id > id_product_start ) then
      set @query := concat( @query, ',\n' );
    end if;

    set @query := concat( @query, '( ', start_id, ', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', 
                          \'0.000000\', 7.317073, \'0.000000\', 100, \'0.000000\', \'0.00\', 
                          1, 1, \'0000-00-00\' ),\n' );
    set @query := concat( @query, '( ', start_id, ', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', 
                          \'0.000000\', 14.634146, \'0.000000\', 100, \'0.000000\', \'0.00\', 
                          0, 1, \'0000-00-00\' ),\n' );
    set @query := concat( @query, '( ', start_id, ', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', 
                          \'0.000000\', 24.390244, \'0.000000\', 100, \'0.000000\', \'0.00\', 
                          0, 1, \'0000-00-00\' ),\n' );

    if ( start_id = max_id ) then
      set id_product_start := start_id;
      leave adding_rows;
    else
      set start_id := start_id + 1;
    end if;
  end loop adding_rows;

  prepare stmt from @query;
  execute stmt;
  drop prepare stmt;
end;
//
delimiter ;
```

Now you can all the SP with start and max values for `id_product`.

```
set @id_start := 5;
set @max_id := 216;
call add_dummy_records( @id_start, @max_id );

-- check if if id_start > 5 and is equal to max_id
select ( @id_start > 5 ), ( @id_start = @max_id );
```

Comment: @siwydym: I think it must be on `drop` statement. Change it to `drop procedure if exists add_dummy_records //`. And it should be working.

Comment: after that i noticed this #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
    set query := concat( @query, start_id, ', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', ' at line 13

Comment: @siwydym: concat was not closed properly. corrected.

Comment: Thanks everybody for effort and time! I found easy way to solve it by export database to csv, edit in excel, save to csv and import to database. works like charm!

Comment: @siwydym: Congratulations.